# Create table on Athena only from certain S3 files (depending on filename)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create a table on Athena from S3 files.
In my bucket, I have different types of files (Activity, Epoch, BodyComp, etc.) and I'd like this table to **contain only "Activity" files** assuming their filenames are like :
"Activity__xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx__yyyyyyyyyy.json"
where :
 - x is a character or a digit
 - y is a digit

I can do that after creating the table with this SELECT statement but the query takes too much time:

```
SELECT *, regexp_extract("$path", '[^/]+$') AS filename
FROM runs
WHERE regexp_extract("$path", '[^/]+$') like 'Activity__%';
```

**I'd like to do it directly in the CREATE TABLE statement.**
I tried this with **"input.regex"** but it didn't work :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS runs(
  summaryId string,
  distanceInMeters float,
  maxHeartRateInBeatsPerMinute int,
  totalElevationGainInMeters float,
  userAccessToken string
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format' = '1',
                      "input.regex" = "^Activity\_\_\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}\_\_\d{10}\.json") 
LOCATION 's3://com.connector/' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that "input.regex" is not the correct parameter to get the filenames.

Thank you for your help,
Max

Comment: There is no direct way of doing this. Either you can rename files starting with _(underscore) so that Athena will ignore them or use CTAS and pass the select query above.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Your comment was really helpful in my case. Not sure why you didn't make it an actual answer. :)

Comment: @Tomty I have added the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of doing this. Either you can rename files starting with `_`(underscore) so that Athena will ignore them or use `CTAS` and pass the select query above.